# Merging two git repositories from some specific commit

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I have to make a merge between repositories. I was working with some people in project A.

Once we finished project A, we started the project B.

Project B has project A as base so we cloned A removed the git files and started working with this files (I don't really know why we did this there were lots of better ways to do that)

So now I have Project A with all of its commits and Project B with an initial commit that includes the whole A and the ones we did working in B

Is there any possibility to move commits from repository B to repository A? (excluding the first one which is the project A)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rep A:

```
a1 --- a2
```

rep B:

```
b1 --- b2
```

The problem here is that a2 and b1, although they have the same content, are not the same commit since they have different ancestry.

Here the very simple example I made, fetching the branch from another repo. `git` creates a branch with a detached branching point:

```
mkdir a
cd a
echo "a1" > asdf.txt
git init
git add asdf.txt 
git commit -m"a1"
echo asdf2 >> asdf.txt
git commit -am"a2"
cd ..
cp -a a b
cd b
rm -rf .git
git init
git add asdf.txt 
echo b1 >> asdf.txt 
git commit -am"b1"
echo b2 >> asdf.txt
git commit -am"b2"
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
cd ../a
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
git fetch ../b master:b_branch
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate
```

results in:

```
* 4de3a97 (b_branch) b2
* 34c116e b1
* 4b25afe (HEAD, master) a2
* 7ac42e8 a1
```

It does not show in the `git log --graph`, but if you visualize the repo with `gitk --all` at that point, you'll see that the history is disconnected.

From there you can rebase the `b_branch` on `master`:

```
git checkout b_branch
git rebase master
```

Chances are you'll get a conflict for the very first commit of `b_branch` (that is not in `master`), but after that you should be good. Solve the conflict manually, `git add` the offending file(s), then `git rebase --continue`.